# adb install apk from URL from mac terminal

Tags: android, macos, terminal-emulator

How to install apk from mac terminal through abd shell command where the apk has to be get from the URL.
`adb install <url>`
results in 
`adb: failed to stat <url>`

Comment: Execute "adb devices" and check if the device is connected or not.

Comment: Can you download the apk from that URL? If so download the APK and run command

Comment: You can use combination of commands first download the file using curl -O <url>, then install with adb.

Comment: @Swayangjit yeah. I can install from local storage.But what I need is to install from build URL

Comment: @sravs I am planning this for automation, so cant do that each time

Comment: @amitsrivastava for that I should store in particular local storage location right.If someone changed, my automation may fail right